# Inkscape 0.92.2 (snap) has not numpy.linalg modules installed

Tags: package-management, snap, cinnamon

when I try to export a shape as dxf I get the following message:
"Failed to import the numpy or numpy.linalg modules. These modules are required by this extension. Please install them and try again."
One library is missing. The inkscape.snap not come with this module, but the inkscape flatpak did.
[message error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2YNkz.png)
Can you fix it?

Comment: This seems like a bug. You can report it here: https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape

Comment: Seems to be already reported as https://bugs.launchpad.net/inkscape/+bug/1748596 .

Answer (score 0):

I think the solution is to install Inkscape from official repository (as traditional stable deb-package):

```
sudo apt-get install inkscape
```

Even 16.04 LTS has [0.91-7ubuntu2, on artful you will get 0.92.2-1build1](https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?suite=all&exact=1&searchon=names&keywords=inkscape).

If you really need 0.92.2 on for example 16.04 LTS you can add [Inkscape Stable PPA](https://code.launchpad.net/~inkscape.dev/+archive/ubuntu/stable):

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:inkscape.dev/stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install inkscape
```

And it would great if you report bug to inkscape's snap maintainers/developers.